# Notification icon on status bar is coming as white box

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notifications

How do i customize the notification icon on the status bar in my phone running Android 5.0. It always comes as a white box(image attached).

The notification icon in the notification bar comes colorful as expected but the status bar icon comes as white square box.[image]l

Answer (score 5):

android 5.0 uses the icon that you give him and puts a color filter on it. If you want to see your icon, you must use an icon with transparency (png). I advice you to set another icon other than the icon of your application and remove the rectangle with rounded border.

Answer (score 1):

[There](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification) is some restrictions for notification icons. And also Lollipop doesn't show exactly what you set. It flatifies the notification icons and also suggest you to use flat style icons.

Comment: The link above now redirects to a generic Google page about icons: https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html
The original link is here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20150518002812/http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#notification

Comment: Thx Binks for old page url, you're right. Now my links redirects to a common tutorial.