# android notification icon showing as white block

Tags: android, image, icons, android-notifications

I have been having trouble with a icon showing with my notification. I have gone trough the [material designs page](https://material.google.com/style/icons.html#) for icons and [Notification doc](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html).

I used different scales, in BMP 256 color format: 360px, 144px, 48px, 24px 16px all continued showing a white block.

I changed format to PNG, used 144px (named "ic_notify_icon", used in code), still no luck.

```
//Global
private NotificationManager mNotifyManager ;
private Notification mNotify;

private void initialize() {
    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    mNotificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_notify_icon);
    mNotificationBuilder.setContentTitle("A Title here");
    mNotificationBuilder.setContentText("Some content text here");
    mNotify = mNotificationBuilder.build();
    ShowNotify();
}

private void ShowNotify(){
    //...some code here
    mNotifyMan.notify(0, mNotify);
    //...some code here
}
```

Any suggestions?

p.s. I had a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532971/notification-icon-on-status-bar-is-coming-as-white-box), also same question but I do not find it helpful/useful, or I just do not understand the requirements...

Comment: What does your notification image look like? Does it have any transparency?

Comment: no, this is a simple white background with a big 5 in color, made in MS paint - a quick icon for debugging

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. In order to keep a consistent look the icons are generated so they can be made to match the theme. You have to think of it as only a foreground color and transparency.

Comment: @CaseyB I added a indepth answer to how I solved my problem, you may look and improve if you feel necessary

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have found the solution!

I only found hints on what the requirements are for a Android Notification (SDK 22 / Version 5.1.1)but after searching for over 4 hours, finally a complete and working solution for this.

Here are the steps I followed and it seems to be inline with what is mentioned on various forums, questions/answers and doc, but no "steps/requirements" of what is needed:

**Creating and preparing your image**

1. Create your image, however you want, take your app icon if you like:
   [image]
   Quick and dirty
2. Download an application to set transparency - I used [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/), it works well
   [image]
   Here is my image in IrfanView
3. Open your image in IrfanView, `click File > Save As or press 's'`
4. You should have a `Save Dialog` open (and a save options dialog, top right - if not, right at the bottom of the save dialog, select the `Save options dialog` checkbox, and it should open)
5. My settings (which were given by default) are:

   - Compression level - 6
   - Use main window color for transparency - Checked
   - Binary Encoding
   - (ICO): Use main window color for transparency - Checked
6. Check the following 2 boxes:

   - Save Transparent Color - Checked (I tried with only this checked, it didn't work - someone can extend on why not)
   - Save Transparentcy as Alpha Channel - Checked
7. Save as PNG file.
   [image]
   Save Box with Save Options

**In Android Studio:**

1. `Right-Click Drawable folder > Add image asset` (any resource folder should do)
   [image]
2. Click on `Notification Icon` from the top drop-down list (default is `Launcher Icon`)
   [image]
3. Select `Image > Browse to image> click ok` 
   [image]
   **You will notice your image is greyscale**

this is normal since the `Lollipop SDK (API 21 - Ver 5.0.1)` only allows this type of color scheme, in searching I came across the materials design page which mentioned something in this line (Someone can extend on why this is)

Below, you will notice your notification icon in different 'dpi resolutions', adding a image normally will show a white block, but adding transparency solves this.

I believe one can use this from a 'colorful' perspective, in this case, *IrfanView* has a default background of black, this creating a "inverted" image in respect to this color (assuming in *IrfanView*, one leaves the "Use main windows color for transparency - checked" ) you can create different and interesting images.

I really hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me. My problem is Android O devices notification icon (white) did not overlay by primary color when scrolling down notification bar.

Answer (score 7):

The notification icon in android must be transparent and have no background color!

If the icon have a rounded color background,
the icon will become a white rounded block.

Only an icon with a very transparent background can be used as a notification  icon.

Answer (score 1):

convert your png icon from this [link](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-notification.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_stat_example). hope it will help you.

Comment: I get the same output in Android studio when I select add image asset > notification icon> select image

Comment: converted image is working

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before, the problem is the size of the image you're using, try to resize it to 32x32 png.

```
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_tend_notification)
                .setContentTitle(Constants.APP_NAME)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setTicker(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: doesn't this limit to a specific screen size e.g. hdpi, implying that a 144px will allow for max res of xxxhdpi, and Android Studio will automatically scale to each of the screen resolutions? or does the notification max res limit me to 32px for all screen sizes?

Comment: I thought the same, But after working so hard on researching the problem, i came across that answer, which seemed to work well with many device including nexus 9 tablet.

Comment: put your png image, inside drawable directory.